# How to use NavigableMap features with Guava's Multimap (with asMap())?

Tags: java, collections, guava, multimap

Let's assume i have something like this:

```
Multimap<Integer, Integer> data = TreeMultimap.create();
```

How can i use `.headMap()` on my data? I suppose, that `TreeMultimap.asMap()` is the way to go.

The documentation ([link](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/index.html)) says, that `TreeMap.asMap()` returns `NavigableMap<K,Collection<V>>`, but i'm not able to get that to work.

```
NavigableMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> test = data.asMap(); // type mismatch
SortedMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>> test = data.asMap(); // type mismatch
```

What am i doing wrong?

Thanks!

PS: I'm using guava 16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of `data` is `Multimap`, not `TreeMultimap`. Also, a `NavigableMap<Integer, Collection<Integer>>`, is not compatible with `NavigableMap<Integer, ArrayList<Integer>>`.

Change your code to:

```
TreeMultimap<Integer, Integer> data = TreeMultimap.create();
NavigableMap<Integer, Collection<Integer>> test = data.asMap();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer in such a short time!